# Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2019 email feedback

Tags: support, survey-2019

Some users received an email to participate in the testing of the Developer Survey 2019. (The email explicitly states not to post questions or links, so please don't ask to disclose this information.)

I wonder where we should leave feedback, especially on errors received during filling in the survey.

Can anyone of the team clarify where we should leave this feedback? Is Meta okay or do you prefer an email?

Comment: Email is definitely the best way. I think the survey team meant to include a "report issues here instead" bullet and it got accidentally clipped, I've just alerted them to your post and they can respond with the appropriate email address to use. We can't really talk about problems with the questions or survey publicly without making some parts of it public too early, so your discretion is super appreciated here. Anita or one of the folks from that team will be by shortly, thank you again!

Comment: I have received email as well from email address do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email and not usre if this is spam or real thing ...

Comment: Thanks for helping us test the Developer Survey! There is a section at the end of the survey itself where we ask for feedback, so you can submit all your thoughts and any problems you had within the test survey itself.

Comment: @JuliaSilge "There is a section at the end of the survey" That is kinda hard if you can't get past page 1 due to a bug.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you use an ad blocker? Try pausing it; Qualtrics doesn't play nicely with ad blockers.

Comment: Is that part of the Survey? "If you can't get past the browser error console, then you can't fill in the survey!" ;) @JuliaSilge

Comment: Still, the question remains: where should we leave feedback in the midst of the process filling in?

Comment: @PatrickHofman _"in the midst of the process filling in?"_ I just typed some notes into notepad and pasted them in the box at the end.

Comment: Still hard if there is an error thrown @George.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I will reach out to you via email

Comment: If there are concerns about trackers and other ad-related things that might be part of the survey, that should definitely be a big warning banner at the top of page 1, e.g. "please turn off any ad blocker you may have, including AdBlock+, uBlock/Origin, Ghostery, etc. or the survey may not work correctly for you"....