# Email "Can you help us test the 2019 Developer Survey?" - is this real?

Tags: support, survey, questionnaire

I got an email asking for exactly that.

The survey looked totally legitimate to me and the survey itself was asking for the same kind of stuff previous surveys asked for. It was also promised that everyone participating gets a 5$ gift card for taking part in order to help find data flaws in the survey. I haven’t received my gift card yet; is there a reason why I haven’t?

Or is it just because I was tricked by a phishing mail and gave away data into a random survey database?

Here is the recipient header:

```
Return-Path: <bounces+5841141-f07c-recipient=example.com@em.stackoverflow.email>
Received: from o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net ([168.245.32.199]) by mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx016 [212.227.15.9]) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 1MWSyX-1goLwQ31Eh-00Y61X for <recipient@example.com>; Tue, 08 Jan 2019 14:01:06 +0100
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=stackoverflow.email; h=content-type:from:list-unsubscribe:mime-version:reply-to:subject:to; s=s1; bh=Pttg8tAo1l9uFuY9BQDbcYSLXeM=; b=TeeMxFFT7VD11yZfKB0buZU DGTW5JG+xgx9FioTmnz+p0Xoo2+MZKFuoxW6QUfaBfyN4UvRhozddtmwkGF+2752 RvHPfQEN5GF6elENzHEja3nUBsvjZbs73P3+5Yt3DwyYdZUvBoe8ETpzDPxd+nA7 2x5c/jhWUKnE8gZq64zU=
Received: by filter0004p1iad2.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter0004p1iad2-15604-5C349EEA-21 2019-01-08 13:00:26.644748831 +0000 UTC m=+33362.341333089
Received: from NTg0MTE0MQ (ec2-34-230-61-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com [34.230.61.2]) by ismtpd0028p1iad2.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id JgOrz-URRPyViZeDjHifzw for <recipient@example.com>; Tue, 08 Jan 2019 13:00:26.623 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=f62f94eebaf92fdcddc9e13f320d0d00871a4560ff8cdd955ccec327a2c8
Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 13:00:26 +0000 (UTC)
Feedback-ID: 704837:497619:7013:iterable
From: "Stack Overflow" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>
List-Unsubscribe: -------------------
Mime-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email
Subject: Can you help us test the 2019 Developer Survey?
To: recipient@example.com
X-Campaign-ID: 497619
X-Message-ID: bbbaf1438819449886d6160861ba1b36
Message-ID: <JgOrz-URRPyViZeDjHifzw@ismtpd0028p1iad2.sendgrid.net>
X-SG-EID: 80vD1REQ+11IKPmWW9TGhw95xUnvXEeqFud9YrElenwaHnLDz97WdterLWXOWmAyf8kalA5xUA0qB+ Y0kBoa4VvFuWPc5Kag6sMVLW5YB+6puqKnvYt5vo2UF+hEsapb/EqsbbzjuZlxoIAev3E/JAHsMzIy SECEk3CY6fdsPDPUV1Mo11ElCxU3gTEc69K/ZdnNvfs3LzkjiUnlmYQpZdAS/QL1f6j+vS5srLiO7S 17tigMcXQ1jVQxilec1L9o
X-SG-ID: SmDFk6fVVFXrSNgMN4Q94e+JntgiU/p4F9LZhXOiebXM38+yhk1o+W1QrS9AJgzd2lJ7lmbi1n32WU 5sWA5G5qgdSj0p7QDpkREEP3gT5XsCPjshxH/a/lVekPFwRD3lHjLVHSR7J8aIKLGx8ujvjlQcFxCh Jto8JLyhVVOjGXo=
Envelope-To: <recipient@example.com>
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V03:K0:WEGonL8vNXQ=:tPHMv43YdeieldCvtMJX6GC2zC KfOy+2rcfyOS0N4jJpW8r25zfA44MBjJs6Pftu+eMVfEWrNcM2Ov39I4Ofx1H4nyObULLZulO Tj1GuJGToXij3cIBnv1E9CQLuOoucUkuP/UvzJY2xZESfaF7KLtUrqQkPO6y8WcQQENRYbCvF gq7S6cfyq9dkYMYuifOroOF9ys09Q7HwDKJ+xeXPzWgiq9C2Bx9pmmMW3GmsHGDZjqbDXUf3h a36lF8Vpuq1EC4pZSW535/+ogv+dJSQBLBlpME9AWERdptRNexKwHjHgnthxaFXWI434yRGtI +Sym1lWCLo4oSx7KFXvEOJKbb0PGGdMj2NkuHY2hJJRSd6WZn0S6GVSjVBaZFtl/tlJAizbsc fqjrrfp3/TecirxZ/oq1Q8slARaGG/I3ztP1THFfyLsMj9QezfFZNidzFPj/RPPyU1UCPM76K WSu/Hlci1s4pDlmNJ69dlud5av5d+J66Fs0p95/Xp4KnJt1CSS+VazaHv/n9Sbdy8/spZFNVp UqT60lSK0zijXgwJ1DSTB3BkLkLYuUtkaxkvZD5QbXLGn4CB1SjR9boz091P9JtqitNM3yqRs TUzI5DZ8sN8ShhkbpKH0ur8YQfqsukTpDW0M/Yd8g7wDl4XmMEeRwwY/ZeGVlfvkWfkOqzku7 uiSJD5v312VnKuNBK5HfZPAkSVdlmTXa7vtsJC0v/q1KAIYbxIM/b2YrEmF/HyEWTBKmjbCs2 6K3lwJgYSv/HTe+Wk6fMjb3WOD1Iow8BmIYH5SurY10c/5D/PHJe577AltMPzhjHuJV0CF6wm 1yyWy/O7REKBSwdtmdEoCJGZaZCisgFbJJGumn8S+SY9IYLmcieTWY0qU8HIzYUoUud1oaGjl 42UQJpxJ3Fffyg1NwQFKUCruCV4eODeA450bEVWYUFgX58KXjFOeDLueLYPwn+07g0h5sk7jG l1uRr89ZO04eLBCwuczzMMadCBOSY7ZJ6kLTaUi1haSDa5jo3afJ4zV4nVY2Vc4c/GgPrdmhG f7QtoKzplYsSz0P5rs4gFfVmqU25Z5Qj1YtMi+208uuMIyH0ATqdAYwDLquqW3ZChd2Xtkrjw Ad1DJac54dRa08MeFFX7/3eCnMnREEYGLuO/AHRZH5DjQMGMiubEb9Tt647cx9dVDau9KLS5r AaNhzCnv+CVw2V8fmfLhgw50b8wZY4GgMPSAHX2o1Epj0F6QUcszdr4+bVEgWH9+Qf7rSV1Vj B6BIKEeu29M29R40YxRNLDVlsYG7BXvE6OFZRw8hseaiyZHNhuXt/eG16s2/hV+U1iGUQxkQY yicTeBIn/80VR0tez32Rh9NrBQK862o52lwSeg/ghlB7nbmm6+jjXZMK7M11RcJETHe+IcXCq Yb8yAHQDfn92bu1lScDvgIELSH/wsE05XdaZunP7KnfSLJhFo+a/awz9FY53VkAC12vkLIlRg pAMPgts/ICEwDcCmI6hVYiozcZ3Eyc4c3j8nwTZvzOaJgSi0+t1WqFAIoi1tVtReWb31jA4s6 ORiXyWEX4mRheLfMkAQCm4TUntE2PMC/4TkPi9t+qz5IUioqUtBkSgYF923et3tT3vF9+uVdz E4iyBDVeFnF0015UXB2wEkpV8IgjZiwSwaAHg1LkfZfv5gCdDr9vzWBu+1EIY21x3r2AH7OGm u0QsEU7XBL6HTQwwbmsQ8Sk+qGNNaJvDeMOFxqkmaiFFrP4ldUQ6wc/QgeR3rL9E5H8fpLhzM gvv4DYGJZwHfnnUkQOuCOsnNJ6FEQbir45rx+NKyi8yCNaCB8SuxBRLH2IuzpH3YSgxdr/AlS 68+T6ohe92wF12k7EwoVG6f+Kro6072cTWD736xkLe9BNCOP9RI81xZ9cdPxi1xQthOO2Hdxs hDAhOkKOuUK15fhm1LTdrSE9BNR5ycPL95WRSW9zTRVcVFlFAATwoH72UM4VyP4J6+UtcnNq0 QyaU0FB1Hhpl7l5zh0o9TzDsWFJF7DU55Y2wK5QK7S9K54iR3nF9iK2DkCXiuDdzurJ8lUKYg VZHpE0HUMJq6bkmiS4RY5N0hUlZYqSCRw/0SoKBIna5YAjJ8OrWQdBZAOaEo6VsfCueDtG/YD FKS2flCy9lbikauiujO62NOTbgj4xKDEizWSfzKlBe+8AbzyBtx9Pqg==
```

Comment: What was the sender address? What links where in the email?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the sender was stackoverflow.email so seemingly legit. But since you can fake the email header thats not reason enough. The link was a qualtrics survey we explicitly were asked to not share, which I will respect as long there is no proof that its a fake

Comment: Right. I think this one is real, there are other posts here about this.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378803/why-havent-i-received-a-gift-card-for-testing-this-years-questionnaire, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378716/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2019-email-feedback

Comment: As for faking an email from header: sure, but that’s easily checked against the rest of the headers. Without seeing at least the headers we can’t realy tell if what you have is the real deal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am not sure what you are asking for. What specific info you want?

Comment: Emails have a lot of metadata, their headers. How you access these depends on your exact email client, and you may want to redact out your own email or the final server addresses in them, but those headers can tell us a lot about where it came from and if the address was forged or not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am using GMX and honestly don't know how to access the headers there, as it is a very enduser prepared interface it has.

Comment: Does https://emailheaders.net/gmx.html help?

Comment: Also see https://support.gmx.com/email/receiving-and-reading/header.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Lemme check.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, it does help. What specific fields would be helpful? Or should I just post the full header? And if so, are there any fields I should anonymize to warrant my own privacy?

Comment: Search and replace your own email address (`recipient@example.com` is a good placeholder). Because you are using an external mail provider, there is no risk of exposing internal IP addresses here. `Received` headers are the most useful here, but other headers provide context and a forgery often either copies those over wrong or simply forget to set them.

Answer (score 4):

The email is real and came from us. Re: the gift card timeline, see this Meta post: [Why haven't I received a gift card for testing this year's questionnaire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378803/why-havent-i-received-a-gift-card-for-testing-this-years-questionnaire)