# Developer Survey 2019 starting date

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

**What is the launch date of the Developer Survey this year?**

I tried to find it but I was unsuccessful. Sorry if it's an obvious question, but I really don't want to miss it.

Comment: This month or next month, if [the previous surveys](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359680/247702) are any indication.

Comment: @Stijn so no official date is yet announced? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It hasn't been announced yet, so keep an eye out for it :) It should appear in the [Community Bulletin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-bulletin/info).

Comment: FWIW, the SE teams are currently ["beta-testing" the survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378716) to some selected participants and asking their feedback, so it might take a while for them to revise and publish the final version to the public.

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks may be....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that took about a week. Looks like the 2019 Developer Survey is out now!

- open date: January 23, 2019
- close date: February 12, 2019

[Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey) | [Blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/23/our-2019-developer-survey-is-open-to-coders-everywhere)